# How to create a column with values related to Concatenated data from excel file

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I created a code that Concatenate column with same name but in different sheets with one `excel` file

and here's my #updated code

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mydir = (os.getcwd()).replace('\\', '/') + '/'

cluster_cell = pd.read_excel(r'' + mydir + 'Cluster_Cell.xlsx', usecols=['CELLNAME'], encoding='latin-1')
GUL_EP_GSM = pd.read_excel(r'' + mydir + 'GU EP20191016171519.xlsx', sheet_name="GSM_CDDData", usecols=['CELLNAME'],
                           encoding='latin-1')
print(GUL_EP_GSM)

GUL_EP_UMTS = pd.read_excel(r'' + mydir + 'GU EP20191016171519.xlsx', sheet_name="UMTS_CDDData", usecols=['CELLNAME'],
                            encoding='latin-1')
print(GUL_EP_UMTS)
GUL_EP_LTE = pd.read_excel(r'' + mydir + 'GU EP20191016171519.xlsx', sheet_name="LTE_CDDData", usecols=['CELLNAME'],
                           encoding='latin-1')
print(GUL_EP_LTE)
appended_cell_name = pd.DataFrame({'CELLNAME': cluster_cell['CELLNAME'] + GUL_EP_GSM['CELLNAME'] + GUL_EP_UMTS['CELLNAME'] + GUL_EP_LTE['CELLNAME']})

mask1 = appended_cell_name['CELLNAME'].isin(GUL_EP_GSM['CELLNAME'])
mask2 = appended_cell_name['CELLNAME'].isin(GUL_EP_UMTS['CELLNAME'])
mask3 = appended_cell_name['CELLNAME'].isin(GUL_EP_LTE['CELLNAME'])

cond=[mask1,mask2,mask3]
values=['GSM','UMTS','LTE']
appended_cell_name['system']=np.select(cond,values)

GUL_EP_GSM['CELLNAME']
GUL_EP_UMTS['CELLNAME']
GUL_EP_LTE['CELLNAME']
appended_cell_name['system'].unique()
print(appended_cell_name)

appended_cell_name.to_excel("Cluser_Cell_Final.xlsx", index=False)
```

So now I need to create a column for this Concatenated called 'System`contains`values`related to`pandas` Objects I have created

To make it in deep....
For example:-
for `GUL_EP_GSM`  Object's I want to add values to the new created `column` with values `GSM`, and for `GUL_EP_UMTS` values I want to add to the new created `column` `UMTS`, and for `GUL_EP_LTE` values I want to add to the new created `column` `LTE`

like the below pictures

this is before and just my code makes

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoxyE.png)

this is after that I want to do

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tQfJ.png)

Any idea for how to do that?

And I need to simplify my code to the easiest way....

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mwx825326/PycharmProjects/MyExcelCombine/MyCopyAndPaste.py", line 11, in <module>
    appended_cell_name=pd.DataFrame({'CELLNAME':cluster_cell + GUL_EP_GSM + GUL_EP_UMTS + GUL_EP_LTE})
  File "C:\Users\mwx825326\PycharmProjects\MyExcelCombine\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 411, in __init__
    mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\mwx825326\PycharmProjects\MyExcelCombine\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 257, in init_dict
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\mwx825326\PycharmProjects\MyExcelCombine\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 77, in arrays_to_mgr
    index = extract_index(arrays)
  File "C:\Users\mwx825326\PycharmProjects\MyExcelCombine\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 358, in extract_index
    raise ValueError("If using all scalar values, you must pass an index")
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

## Print OutPut

`appended_cell_name`

```
       CELLNAME system
0     3129648.0      0
1     3129652.0      0
2     3129656.0      0
3     3141617.0      0
4     3141621.0      0
...         ...    ...
2347        NaN      0
2348        NaN      0
2349        NaN      0
2350        NaN      0
2351        NaN      0
```

`GUL_EP_GSM`

```
     CELLNAME
0       10169
1       10170
2       10171
3       10349
4       10350
..        ...
124     54237
125     54996
126     54997
127     54998
128     55966
```

`GUL_EP_UMTS`

```
     CELLNAME
0     1106382
1     1106383
2     1106384
3     1019810
4     1019811
..        ...
262   1102891
263   1102892
264   1018393
265   1018394
266   1018395
```

`GUL_EP_LTE`

```
     CELLNAME
0     2002388
1     2002389
2     2002390
3     2100118
4     2100119
..        ...
538   2304376
539   2304377
540   2205890
541   2205891
542   2205892
```

`mask1` output

```
0       False
1       False
2       False
3       False
4       False
        ...  
2347    False
2348    False
2349    False
2350    False
2351    False
Name: CELLNAME, Length: 2352, dtype: bool
```

`mask2` output

```
0       False
1       False
2       False
3       False
4       False
        ...  
2347    False
2348    False
2349    False
2350    False
2351    False
Name: CELLNAME, Length: 2352, dtype: bool
```

`mask3` output

```
0       False
1       False
2       False
3       False
4       False
        ...  
2347    False
2348    False
2349    False
2350    False
2351    False
Name: CELLNAME, Length: 2352, dtype: bool
```

output of

```
print(GUL_EP_LTE.info())
print(GUL_EP_UMTS.info())
print(GUL_EP_LTE.info())
```

is

```
[2352 rows x 2 columns]
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 543 entries, 0 to 542
Data columns (total 1 columns):
CELLNAME    543 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 4.3 KB
None
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 267 entries, 0 to 266
Data columns (total 1 columns):
CELLNAME    267 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 2.1 KB
None
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 543 entries, 0 to 542
Data columns (total 1 columns):
CELLNAME    543 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 4.3 KB
None
```

`print(appended_cell_name. info())`

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2352 entries, 0 to 2351
Data columns (total 2 columns):
CELLNAME    129 non-null float64
system      2352 non-null object
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 45.9+ KB
None
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201057/discussion-on-question-by-mahmoud-al-haroon-how-to-create-a-column-with-values-r).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need:

```
GUL_EP_GSM=GUL_EP_GSM.astpye(float)
GUL_EP_UMTS=GUL_EP_UMTS.astpye(float)
GUL_EP_LTE=GUL_EP_LTE.astpye(float)
#appended_cell_name['CELLNAME']=appended_cell_name['CELLNAME'].astype(int) #or convert appended_cell_name to int
```

**because the type of appended_cell_name['CELLNAME'] is float**

Then your code would be:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mydir = (os.getcwd()).replace('\\', '/') + '/'

cluster_cell = pd.read_excel(r'' + mydir + 'Cluster_Cell.xlsx', usecols=['CELLNAME'], encoding='latin-1')

GUL_EP_GSM = pd.read_excel(r'' + mydir + 'GU EP20191016171519.xlsx', sheet_name="GSM_CDDData", usecols=['CELLNAME'],
                           encoding='latin-1')


GUL_EP_UMTS = pd.read_excel(r'' + mydir + 'GU EP20191016171519.xlsx', sheet_name="UMTS_CDDData", usecols=['CELLNAME'],
                            encoding='latin-1')


GUL_EP_LTE = pd.read_excel(r'' + mydir + 'GU EP20191016171519.xlsx', sheet_name="LTE_CDDData", usecols=['CELLNAME'],
                           encoding='latin-1')

#converting to float
GUL_EP_GSM=GUL_EP_GSM.astpye(float)
GUL_EP_UMTS=GUL_EP_UMTS.astpye(float)
GUL_EP_LTE=GUL_EP_LTE.astpye(float)

#print dataframes astype float
print(GUL_EP_GSM)
print(GUL_EP_UMTS)
print(GUL_EP_LTE)
#creating appended_cell_name dataframe
appended_cell_name = pd.DataFrame({'CELLNAME': cluster_cell['CELLNAME'] + GUL_EP_GSM['CELLNAME'] + GUL_EP_UMTS['CELLNAME'] + GUL_EP_LTE['CELLNAME']})

#creating mask with isin
mask1 = appended_cell_name['CELLNAME'].isin(GUL_EP_GSM['CELLNAME'])
mask2 = appended_cell_name['CELLNAME'].isin(GUL_EP_UMTS['CELLNAME'])
mask3 = appended_cell_name['CELLNAME'].isin(GUL_EP_LTE['CELLNAME'])

#using np.select
cond=[mask1,mask2,mask3]
values=['GSM','UMTS','LTE']
appended_cell_name['system']=np.select(cond,values)

#print appended_cell_name
print(appended_cell_name)
#save in excell
appended_cell_name.to_excel("Cluser_Cell_Final.xlsx", index=False)
```

---

you have three data frames called: GUL_EP_GSM,GUL_EP_UMTS,GUL_EP_LTE. Then you need check with [Series.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) 
if the values ​​in the CELLNAME column of the appended_cell_name data frame are in the column of each of those data frames and fill in the system column accordingly.

the only thing you have to change my solution is the label of the columns that is per example:

`GUL_EP_GSM['name_of_colum_in_your data']` instead of

```
GUL_EP_GSM ['GUL_EP_GSM']
```

---

Use [np.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) + [Series.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

**preparing the data**

```
GUL_EP_GSM=pd.DataFrame({'CELLNAME':[53119,53120,53121,54438,54439,54440,55976,55977,55978]})
GUL_EP_UMTS=pd.DataFrame({'CELLNAME':[41773,41774,41775,44620,44621,44622]})
GUL_EP_LTE=pd.DataFrame({'GELLNAME':[2303909,2303923,2303924]})
appended_cell_name=pd.DataFrame({'CELLNAME':[53119,53120,53121,54438,54439,54440,55976,55977,55978,41773,41774,41775,44620,44621,44622,2303909,2303923,2303924]})
```

---

**Creating mask**

```
mask1=appended_cell_name['CELLNAME'].isin(GUL_EP_GSM['CELLNAME'])
mask2=appended_cell_name['CELLNAME'].isin(GUL_EP_UMTS['CELLNAME'])
mask3=appended_cell_name['CELLNAME'].isin(GUL_EP_LTE['CELLNAME'])
```

> Solve with [np.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

Then you apply [np.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
cond=[mask1,mask2,mask3]
values=['GSM','UMTS','LTE']
appended_cell_name['system']=np.select(cond,values)
print(appended_cell_name)
```

---

> Also you can use [Series.mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html)(This is other solution):

```
appended_cell_name['system']= ( appended_cell_name['CELLNAME'].mask(mask1,'GSM')
                                                              .mask(mask2,'UMTS')
                                                              .mask(mask3,'LTE') )
print(appended_cell_name)
```

---

**Output:**

```
    CELLNAME system
0      53119    GSM
1      53120    GSM
2      53121    GSM
3      54438    GSM
4      54439    GSM
5      54440    GSM
6      55976    GSM
7      55977    GSM
8      55978    GSM
9      41773   UMTS
10     41774   UMTS
11     41775   UMTS
12     44620   UMTS
13     44621   UMTS
14     44622   UMTS
15   2303909    LTE
16   2303923    LTE
17   2303924    LTE
```

**DataFrame used:**

```
print(GUL_EP_GSM)
   GUL_EP_GSM
0       53119
1       53120
2       53121
3       54438
4       54439
5       54440
6       55976
7       55977
8       55978
```

---

```
print(GUL_EP_UMTS)
      CELLNAME
0        41773
1        41774
2        41775
3        44620
4        44621
5        44622
```

---

```
print(GUL_EP_LTE)

     CELLNAME
0     2303909
1     2303923
2     2303924
```

Comment: why gives me this error
`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'astpye'`?

Answer (score 0):

not sure to understand well, but you can add such a column before concatenation:

`GUL_EP_GSM['system']='GSM'
GUL_EP_UMTS['system']='UMTS'
GUL_EP_LTE['system']='LTE'`

and then concatenate

Comment: thanks a lot bro your closing from what I need that really creates the column but with empty values and I need now to fill this column with need value

Comment: sorry i didnt understand, can you re-explain your issue? system column should not be empty

Comment: also how should cluster_cell 'system' column be filled?

Comment: Ok Look as you see my question `before` is my code to do, and `after` that actually I need to do..... what your code means that's create a column called `System` but with empty values I need to fill the values like in the `after` picture , I hope you under stand me :)

Comment: my code create a column with empty values only for cluster_cell values as you didnot tell how you want to fill it

Comment: the cluster  cell is already filled, but I need to fill for other 3 objects thhat's all :)

Comment: to be more clearer lets say the object called `GUL_EP_GSM` contains 10 values in column called `CELLNAME`, So I need to a create a column called `system` fills with `GSM` values parallely to the `CELLNAME` with 10 values of `GSM` also..... and same process for the other 2 columns

Comment: I do not need this please check the edit and conversation